# get city, country and ip from a visitor on production mode with rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rails-geocoder

I have installed http://www.rubygeocoder.com/ in a project rails in a production server but this gem in my production server not works fine for me...

I'm using mongoid.

I write these methods in views in my development environment and works fine:

```
<%= request.ip %>   
<%= request.location.city %>    
<%= request.location.country %>
```

and I get:  `127.0.0.1 Reserved`

this result its usually because I am working in localhost.

However after make a deploy with capistrano in the production server in linode I get error with these methods, I can see in my production log the next error:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 909ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `location' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x00000005aa8570>):
```

Why I get this error in my production server for these methods?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was fixed. thank you to alexreisner on https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/239.

After you install this gem, you must restart your production server. if you want that geocoder does work fine.

After restart my linode server this gem does work fine for me :D.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If you are on development try using

```
  request.remote_ip
```

instead of:

```
  request.ip
```

I am not that sure if it will work

Comment: In development mode works fine for me. I need it in production mode. In production mode does not works for me... thank you